# Angular2 component with selector not in the html

Tags: angular, typescript

in the following pluker http://plnkr.co/edit/MC7gO55TGkQTrxaJnJir?p=preview

in the DashboardComponent class, in the file

```
 Dashboard.Component.ts
```

is defined a @component with a selector but in the file .html 
there is no selector equivalent, you can explain me how is possible?
you are not forced to define the selector tag ?

Comment: You've linked the wrong Plnkr.

Comment: the plunker is empty

Comment: updated the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The router uses `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` which doesn't need the selector to match HTML. See also [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468) for an example.

Answer (score 3):

The `DashboardComponent` is used in the `Router`. A router component does not need a `selector` property.

Answer (score 0):

The Angular router lets you route to a component directly - have a look at app/app-routing.module.ts:
`{ path: 'dashboard',  component: DashboardComponent },`

See the "Add Routing" link of this for more detail:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html